# WPF Text block gray out text

Tags: wpf, textblock

I want to gray out text in the WPF text block. how do i make it?

Regards
Raju

Comment: The question asks about *text block*, but the accepted answer is for *TextBox*. I'd edit the answer, but the web search for TextBlock brought me here and the other answers are what I was looking for...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On C#:

```
textBox.Foreground = Brushes.Gray;
```

On XAML:

```
<TextBox Foreground="Gray" />
```

To disable it (will change background too):

```
textBox.IsEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 9):

TextBlocks do not grayout automaticly when disabled

you can use a style to do this for you

```
    <Style x:Key="DisableEnableTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
        </Trigger>
        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
            <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 8):

The `IsEnabled` flag for a `textblock` does not grey the text. [This post](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/07/04/differences-between-label-and-textblock/) details the differences between `textblock` and label. It also shows the XAML to add a trigger on `IsEnabled` to grey the text.

Answer (score 6):

You can set the [TextBlock.Foreground](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textblock.foreground.aspx) property to any color (technically, any Brush).  If you want it to be grayed out, just set:

```
<TextBlock Text="Foo" Foreground="Gray" />
```

If you want it to look "disabled", you can set [IsEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.isenabled.aspx) to false:

```
<TextBlock Text="Foo" IsEnabled="false" />
```

Comment: I want to use IsEnabled flag. once i set it to false it doesn't have any effect. what could be the problem?

Comment: @user209293: How did you set it to false?

Comment: The IsEnabled flag for a textblock does not grey the text.

Comment: @Natxo This depends entirely on teh template being used, but yes, with the default one, the text is not greyed out.  That's why I specifically mentioned setting hte foreground.

Comment: @Reed I meant that there is no "disabled" look for the textblock, of course unless you retemplate or style it.

Comment: What if "Gray" isn't the disabled text color on that system?  Shouldn't you be using a static resource brush that references a system color?

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 Depends on what the OP wants - "greyad out" suggests gray - if they want it to appear disabled, then definitely use a system color brush.

Comment: Right, but what if it's the wrong gray for the user's desktop theme? -- It would be weird if half of the controls on your form disabled to the proper shade of gray and the other half to some other arbitrary shade of gray that happened to match the developer's color scheme. -- You should really be referring to the System Colors when you're trying to match them (which is clearly the intention here).

Comment: If you want to TextBlocks to grayout when disabled you need to use a style


    <Style x:Key="DisableEnableTextBlock" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="1" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="False">
                <Setter Property="Opacity" Value=".5" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>

Answer (score 1):

The trouble with using the TextBox is that there's a box round it.  If you use Label (with Content="Foo") then you can toggle the text colour with IsEnabled. Otherwise it behaves like TextBlock for a short heading/label.

Answer (score 0):

For WinUI set the Opacity property to something around 0.5.

Answer (score -3):

Use TextBox instead and set `IsReadOnly = true` or `IsEnabled = false`